# How to fix 'Sorry, Something went wrong' error while adding bot channel in Azure bot services

Tags: azure-bot-service

I'm not able to add cortana channel to Bot services. It shows 'Sorry, Something went wrong'

I have created a bot service with core bot C# template and deployed it. The chat service is working in Web chat without issues.

I wanted to create a new cortana skills but adding cortana to bot is causing issue[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYLFq.png)

Comment: Is the bot you are working on part of a subscription on a company or organizational tenant or is this a personal subscription?

Comment: add code please

Comment: @StevenKanberg - It is created as part of personal subscription - free trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a recent update in Azure portal, this issue got resolved. Now i'm able to extend the channel to cortana

Answer (score 0):

Does your skill exit without a response?

Try these: https://github.com/microsoft/cortana-skills-samples/tree/master/Consumer/CSharp/V4Patches